# HTML how to align text center, and right with certain margin?

Tags: html, css

- I want "me, center!" at the center of the page.
- I want "me, not right!" have some margin (10px for instance) to the right.
- I want them in one row.

[image]
Thanks!

```css
p {
  text-align: center !important;
}

pp {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<pp>me, not right!</pp>
<p>me, center!</p>
```

Comment: flex and a pseudo could help, https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bJJxgX there's duplicates but did not find the one :(

Comment: I know flex is a very powerful and state-of-art-maybe tool, but I am afraid it may disrupt other sections of my page. But anyway, my problem is solved, if I need to add more features to my page in the futrue, I will definitely consider using flex at the basic structure!

Comment: flex is only another value/way to display elements, what matters is to use what fits the best your needs. float, display:table, , display:block are not not obsolete but have different purpose ;) grid is not any better, just different . your layout with flex, requires a pseudo to mimic your layout, without the pseudo, doing the trick, flex is useless here.(IMHO i avoid absolute, it seems solid & easy at first, but then, it doesn't care about any other content laying in the page. it can  be hidden overflowing the window, or stand upon anything else (form,text,img,another absolute element, :(  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this, I'd put both paragrahps inside a container, which I position relatively; then I just set the `.right` paragraph to `position: absolute` and with this the initial centered paragraph will use the full width of the container and be perfectly centered.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Following styles just for presentation */

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p.right {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="right">me, not right!</p>
  <p>me, center!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, this is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

`pp` isn't a valid HTML tag.

You're nearly there though. The following should set you on the right track if I've understood correctly. Set a paragraph to have text aligned to the center and then add some `span` tags floated to the right.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.push-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>text align center <span class="push-right">text align right</span></p>
```

---

To answer [your question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911449/html-how-to-align-text-center-and-right-with-certain-margin/55911507#comment98477976_55911507) it sounds like you need to reset the margins of your `body` and `html` tags to ensure the `p` tag spans the full width of the actual page.

Adding these additional rules should achieve what you're after assuming no other complex layouts etc.

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.push-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

That should ensure that the `html` and `body` tags aren't pushing everything on the page inwards a bit and also force all paragraph tags to span the full width of the page with *block style* element properties.

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you make "text align center" at the center of the PAGE? Right now, it has the same amount of white margins to its left and right, but there is an extra text on the right, so "text align center" is skewed to the left

Comment: See my updated answer, assuming no other undocumented HTML, that should give you what you're after I think.

Comment: I do have some other layouts in my page, but the accepted answer solved my problem, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to display your paragraph tags as inline. Float will push the elements to the end of the page or beginning depending on float: left or float: right.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>me center</p>
    <p>me, not right</p>
</div>
```

stylesheet:

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    margin-right: 10px /* however much margin you want. */
}
```